# Impulse changes after reloading scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody, skscene

I am applying an impulse to a SKSpriteNode 'char' using the following code:

```
    randX = arc4random_uniform(20) - 10
    randXConv = CGFloat(randX)

    char.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    char.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: randXConv, dy: 23))
```

When the game ends I present EndGameScene:

```
    let skView = self.view! as SKView

    let scene = EndGameScene(size: self.frame.size)
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    let sceneTransition = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.3)
    skView.presentScene(scene, transition: sceneTransition)
```

However, after the 'retry' button is pressed in EndGameScene and the GameScene is presented again, the impulse does not make the node 'char' travel as high as it did upon first load:

```
    let skView = self.view! as SKView

    let scene = GameScene(size: self.frame.size)
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    let sceneTransition = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.3)
    skView.presentScene(scene, transition: sceneTransition)
```

I think it is something to do with the scene or the gravity but I could be wrong.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you try with a constant impulse instead of random and check whether the node travels the same?

Comment: yes, the impulse still changes